# Distinguish classes with different colors Networkx

Tags: networkx

I have a huge dataset of 80,000 rows , I want to draw a meaningful graph in networkx using 2 dataframes (nodes and edges)

In "nodes", I have : actor1 , category_id(int :numerical value from 0 - 7 describe the type , and fatalities (float representing the number of injured or killed people))

In "edges" : "actor1", "actor2", "interaction: float 64"

my aim is to draw a graph with different colors according to category_id and different sizes based on number of fatalities

I started thid code which run perfectly until I tried to retrieve interaction and fatalities to calculate wights of nodes as follows

```
nodes = ACLED_to_graph[['actor1','category_id','fatalities']]
edges = ACLED_to_graph[['actor1','actor2','interaction']]

# Initiate the graph
G4 = nx.Graph()

for index, row in nodes.iterrows():
    G4.add_node(row['actor1'], category_id=row['category_id'], nodesize=row['fatalities'])

for index, row in edges.iterrows():
    G4.add_weighted_edges_from([(row['actor1'], row['actor2'], row['interaction'])])

#greater_than_ = [x for x in G.nodes(data=True) if x[2]['nodesize']>15]

# Sort nodes by degree 
sorted(G4.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# remove anonymous nodes whose degree are <2 and <200 
cond1 = [node for node,degree in G4.degree() if degree>=200]
cond2 = [node for node,degree in G4.degree() if degree<4]
remove = cond1+cond2
G4.remove_nodes_from(remove)
G4.remove_edges_from(remove)

# Customize the layout
pos=nx.spring_layout(G4, k=0.25, iterations=50)

# Define color map for classes    
color_map = {0:'#f1f0c0',1:'#f09494', 2:'#eebcbc', 3:'#72bbd0', 4:'#91f0a1', 5:'#629fff', 6:'#bcc2f2',  
             7:'#eebcbc' }

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
options = {
    'edge_color': '#FFDEA2',
    'width': 1,
    'with_labels': True,
    'font_weight': 'regular',
}

colors = [color_map[G4.node[node]['category_id']] for node in G4.node]
#sizes = [G.node[node]['interaction'] for node in G]

"""
Using the spring layout : 
- k controls the distance between the nodes and varies between 0 and 1
- iterations is the number of times simulated annealing is run
default k=0.1 and iterations=50
"""
#node_color=colors,
#node_size=sizes,

nx.draw(G4,node_color=colors, **options,cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#555555")
```

I am also removing some nodes with degrees greater than 200 and less than 3 to simplify the graph and make it more appealing.

I am getting the following error :

```
colors = [color_map[G4.node[node]['category_id']] for node in G4.node]

KeyError: 'category_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving mathematical operation using nodes attributes can be summarized as follows :

## 1 -After the subsetting the dataframe, we initialize the graph

```
nodes = ACLED_to_graph[['actor1','category_id','interaction']]
edges = ACLED_to_graph[['actor1','actor2','fatalities']]

# Initiate the graph
G8 = nx.Graph()
```

## 2- Add edges attributes first (I emphasize the use of from_pandas_edgelist)

```
for index, row in edges.iterrows():
        G8 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, 'actor1', 'actor2', ['fatalities'])
```

## 3- Next we add nodes attributes using add_note, other techniques such as set_nodes_attributes didn't work in pandas

```
for index, row in nodes.iterrows():
    G8.add_node(row['actor1'], category_id=row['category_id'], interaction=row['interaction'])
```

## 4- Sort nodes by degree to select the most connected nodes (I am choosing nodes with degrees more than 3 and less than 200)

```
sorted(G8.degree, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# remove anonymous nodes whose degree are <2 and <200 
cond1 = [node for node,degree in G8.degree() if degree>=200]
cond2 = [node for node,degree in G8.degree() if degree<3]
remove = cond1+cond2
G8.remove_nodes_from(remove)
G8.remove_edges_from(remove)
```

## 5- set the color based on degree (calling node.degree)

```
node_color = [G8.degree(v) for v in G8]
```

## 6- set the edge size based on fatalities

```
edge_width = [0.15*G8[u][v]['fatalities'] for u,v in G8.edges()]
```

## 7- set the node size based on interaction

```
node_size = [list(nx.get_node_attributes(G8, 'interaction').values()) for v in G8]
```

I used get.node_attribute instead pandas to access the features which allowed me to list the dictionary and convert it to a matrix of values , ready to compute.

## 8- Select the most important edges based on atalities

```
large_edges = [x for x in G8.edges(data=True) if x[2]['fatalities']>=3.0]
```

## 9- Finally, draw the network and edges seperately

```
 nx.draw_networkx(G8, pos, node_size=node_size,node_color=node_color, alpha=0.7, with_labels=False, width=edge_width, edge_color='.4', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G8, pos, edgelist=large_edges, edge_color='r', alpha=0.4, width=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

without the input data it is a bit hard to tell for sure, but it looks as if you are not constructing the graph nodes with a property 'category_id'. In the `for index, row in nodes.iterrows():` you assign the data in the nodes dictionary, key 'category_id' to the property "group".

you can confirm this to be the case by checking what keys are set for an example node in your graph, e.g. `print(G4.node['actor1 '].keys())`.

To fix this, either
a) change the assignment

```
for index, row in nodes.iterrows():
    G4.add_node(row['actor1'], category_id=row['category_id'], nodesize=row['interaction'])
```

or b) change the lookup

```
colors = [color_map[G4.node[node]['group']] for node in G4.node]
```

Comment: I tried to print print(G4.node['actor1 '].keys()) , i got keyError : actor1, but when printing the value of a node name like G4.node['Operation Restoring Hope'].keys() , I got the following output:  dict_keys(['category_id', 'nodesize']).  I changed the code above based on your recommendation which is logic but I am still getting the same error : KeyError : category_id

Comment: edges.head(1)
Out[62]: 
                          actor1  :Operation Restoring Hope   ,                                                   actor2  :Military Forces of Yemen (2016-) Supreme Polit...         interaction : 18.0============== while nodes have the following format :  actor1                                category_id  fatalities
          Operation Restoring Hope            0             0.0 @bonlenfum

Comment: nodes.dtypes
Out[64]: 
actor1          object
category_id      int64
fatalities     float64
dtype: object | edges.dtypes
Out[65]: 
actor1          object
actor2          object
interaction    float64
dtype: object @bonlenfum

Comment: well it seems that you are not populating the nodes attributes consistently.  You can write more "defensive" code that uses `row.get('category_id', default_val)` (where `default_val` is something sensible in case there is no value for category_id in a particular row).  But perhaps there is a problem in concept, not just in missing data in rare cases? What does `ACLED_to_graph` look like? The list inside list syntax is not very clear.

Comment: the data frame is well defined and all items are consistently called, but I discovered a workaround for calling a anode attribute and perform a mathematical calculation after few trials which I will share it in a full demonstration as an answer below